# Using Observable for Instagram4Android

Tags: java, android

I want to Use [Instagram4Android](https://github.com/charlieAndroidDev/Instagram4Android) Repository,
I have the following errors While using example!

My Code:

```
private Observable<InstagramLoginResult> attemptLogin(final Instagram4Android instagram) {

    Observable<InstagramLoginResult> observable = Observable.create(observableEmitter -> {

        instagram.setup();
        observableEmitter.onNext(instagram.login());

    });

    return observable;

}
```

Errors:

1- java.util.observable does not have type parameters

2- cannot resolve method create and onNext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first error happens because you have imported the wrong Observable class. As the error msg suggests `java.util.observable` class does not support the generics(type parameters).Instead, try importing the Observable class in the RxAndroid by,

`import io.reactivex.Observable`